# Php extension problems

Tags: php, c, php-internals

I get a tricky problem when i am trying to create a php extension with c, with an array returned.
I do as some tutorials said, but i need to return an array.
`array_init(return_array)` in all examples is said to initialize an returning-array, but i find nowhere the `return_array` is declared. So, i got error:
**`error C2065: 'return_array' : undeclared identifier`**, however, if i add :

**`zval * return_array ;`**

But it throws **your app cannot read address 000000f**
why?

Can you give me a detailed extension example containing array-returning....thanx millions times

Comment: look at nearly any function that returns an array. can you post the full code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the array, just initialize `return_value`:

```
array_init(return_value);
```

`return_value` is a `zval*`, declared by the `PHP_FUNCTION()` macro.

Answer (score 0):

The following code gives an example of returning array:

```
array_init(return_value);
add_index_long(rturn_value,0,10);
add_index_stringl(return_value,1,"test",1);
zval * record;
MAKE_STD_ZVAL(record);
array_init(record);
add_assoc_long(record,"key",1);
add_index_zval(return_value,2,record);
return;
```

This will return the following results in php namespace, which cover most php extension returning scenarios:

```
array(
    10,
    "test",
    array(
        "key" => 1
    )
)
```